# PHP basic auth doesn't work

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement small API and for this I must check user's API keys with basic auth, but for some reason even simplest example doesn't work:

```
<?php

include '../config.inc.php';

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];    
$validated = false;
if( $user == $api_key );
    $validated = true;
if (!$validated) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="API"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  exit ("Not authorized");
}
```

and I think that the problem is that I'am using `mod_rewrite` for accessing api itself (different api modules are included depends on what page have been accessed), here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_admin/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

When accessing index.php I got this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_admin\api\index.php on line 5
```

However, on the upper folder it works fine. What could cause this problem and how to solve the issue? Thank you.

Comment: There are a few things wrong here. 1. In the first call, `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` will never exist, since the browser haven't gotten the header (which you set below) yet and the user haven't filled in any info. 2. You have `echo $user;` before you send the headers. You can't output anything before sending headers or you will get "headers already sent".

Comment: This example worked fine when I put it to a directory above api folder. Even without sendind any additional headers. Echo user is for debugging purpose only.

Comment: This example can never have worked as expected. At least not with this exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code. First you need to check if you actually got the user:

```
$user = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : null;
```

Then your if statement doesn't do anything and `$validated` will always be true. To resolve this, remove the semi-colon:

```
if($user && $user == $api_key ) $validated = true;
```

Or even better:

```
$validated = $user && $user == $api_key
```

Also don't check with `isset` since the variable is definitely set, just check that it's non-null as in my change above.

Comment: Don't forget that there's also a `echo $user;` _before_ the headers are sent.

Comment: I see, but problem that the actually basic auth dialog never appears.

Comment: @AlexPetrov Read this answer again, specifically: _"Then your if statement doesn't do anything and $validated will always be true. To resolve this, remove the semi-colon:"_. That's why the auth dialog never appears.

Comment: @AlexPetrov, try to put just `header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="API"'); header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');` in your file to confirm that the dialog appears. Then it means you only need to fix the logic that leads to it. As @Magnus mentioned, you also need to make sure you don't echo anything before calling `header()`